# how to change change ui with async in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I try to develop a mobile app in xamarin forms.
I have news list and i am using SQLite for store that.
When my main page open, before i get the news from SQLite and then i try to get new news from web API. I can save the new news in SQLite but my UI hasn't changed. How can i fix that?

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        database = new Helper.xxxDatabase(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "xxx.db3"));

        SetLocalDBMainNews();

        Task.Run(async () => { await GetNewsAsync(); });
    }
    void SetLocalDBMainNews()
    {
        if(database.TableExists("News"))
        {
            List<News> newsList = database.GetNewsData();
            if (newsList.Count > 0)
            {
                MaiNewsList.ItemsSource = newsList.Where(x => x.Type.Equals((int)NewsType.MainNews)).OrderBy(x => x.Sort).ToList();
            }
        }
        else
            database.CreateNewsTable();
    }
    private async Task GetNewsAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var register = database.GetRegisterData();
            string url = "http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/News/GetPublishedNews";
            var response = Tools.Send(url, "GET", register.Token);
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse<List<News>>>(response);
            if (result.HasError == false)
            {
                var newsList = result.Value;
                database.DeleteAllNews();
                foreach(var n in newsList)
                {
                    database.Insert(n);
                }

                MaiNewsList.ItemsSource = newsList.Where(x => x.Type.Equals((int)NewsType.MainNews)).OrderBy(x => x.Sort).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch{}
    }
```

The code works for saving new news to SQLite but i couldn't bind the news to UI in async.

Edit :

After jason's answer, here is the my code latest version
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread solve the my problem.

```
private async Task GetNewsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var register = database.GetRegisterData();
        string url = "http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/News/GetPublishedNews";
        var response = Tools.Send(url, "GET", register.Token);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse<List<News>>>(response);
        if (result.HasError == false)
        {
            var newsList = result.Value;
            database.DeleteAllNews();
            foreach(var n in newsList)
            {
                database.Insert(n);
            }

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                MaiNewsList.ItemsSource = newsList.Where(x => x.Type.Equals((int)NewsType.MainNews)).OrderBy(x => x.Sort).ToList();
            });
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI changes need to happen on the UI thread using `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () =>
{
    MaiNewsList.ItemsSource = newsList.Where(x => x.Type.Equals((int)NewsType.MainNews)).OrderBy(x => x.Sort).ToList();
});
```

Comment: thanks @jason, try this but it didn't work, what did I wrong?
private async Task GetNewsAsync(){
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        MaiNewsList.ItemsSource = newsList.Where(x => x.Type.Equals((int)NewsType.MainNews)).OrderBy(x => x.Sort).ToList();
                    });
}

Comment: did you remove all of the other code from GetNewsAsync?

Comment: No i didn't remove. just all code lines didn't fit to comment area. I will send as a new post.

Comment: are you SURE your LINQ query is correct and returning data?  Are you SURE you're not getting any exceptions?

Comment: i am sure. because when i close app, and then re-open, i can see new news. it doesn't show at first time

Comment: that sounds like an assumption you're making.  There are two different code paths here - just because one works doesn't mean that the other does, even if they use very similar code.  Use the debugger to actually verify that it is doing what you expect it to.

Comment: hi jason, you were right, after debugging async task, there was sqlite error when records insert, i fix the bug and then Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread works fine, thank you.